# "Specified Cast is invalid" Error in WinForm application

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community version 2015. There have been many questions on this issue, but my problem was not covered in them completely. Basically i am working in Windows Form Application (C#) with MySql(phpmyadmin - wamp) database. I am creating a simple windows form application to get Input, Update/Delete the data, Display the elements in Data Grid View and Search any record. I am facing problem in Updating the record. Compiler continuously gives me the same error, that is; "Specified Cast is Invalid". My Code is given bellow:
.

```
private void button_update(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
   { 
    MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;port=3306;database=hyder;uid=root;Encrypt=false;AllowUserVariables=True;Usecompression=True;");
    int id = (int)dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value;
    cn.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "update record set r_name='" + textBox1.Text + "',r_address='" + textBox2.Text + "',r_phone='" + textBox3.Text + "',r_comment='" + textBox4.Text + "' where r_id='" + id;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Record Updated!");
    cn.Close();
 }
catch (Exception x) { MessageBox.Show("Error:" + x.Message); }
}
```

---

What is the problem with this code ?

Comment: And the line where you get the error is?

Comment: Have you run it with the debugger? Which line does it specifically throw the error on? I would suspect `int id = ...` - what is the data type of `(int)dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value`?

Comment: I suggest you research the terms "SQL injection" and "parameterized query"; building your query string like that is bad practice and will bite you at some point.

Comment: Has already bitten, look at the missing closing quotes after id...

Comment: Is this a run time error or compiler error? dose the project build and when you click the update button throws an error?

Comment: It  was a runtime error. Each time I pressed the update button, it kept on throwing me the error of "specified cast".
There was a problem with type casting in line number 2 in the try block. instead of using int id = (int)dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value; ---- I used int id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value); and it worked perfectly. I am still confused why the compiler gave error with (int) and int.Parse.

Comment: The .Value of the selected row cell could possibly be of any object type - not every object can be cast to a int. Say for example the the ID (.Value) was a numerical string, even though the value in the string could be a valid integer, strings are not implicitly convertible to int so the casting it is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
int id = (int)dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value;
```

with

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
```